# How to ceil decimal point?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

As `round` will round either up or down, it can't be used in my case all though you can control the decimal point.

The problem is `floor` and `ceil` does not allow to control the decimal point, in case of floor you can use `truncate` which will turn:
`123.1233` to `123.12`,which is basically the same.

But in case of ceil when you want to turn `123.123` to `123.13`. How can this be done?

Comment: `123.123` to `123.13` isn't mathematically correct approximation. Are you sure, you want to achieve it?

Comment: Give me then some additional information. What about number `123.990`? Should i change it into `124.00`? In other words: you want to approximate every value to floor on second decimal point?

Comment: the number can only be x.xx5 actually, but ya it should be 124.00 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. multiply by 100
2. ceil the result
3. multiply by 1.0 to get float
4. divide by 100

Comment: Well this will work, but isn't there some function in mysql that does that?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

`FLOOR(100*your_number)/100`

Comment: Works with CEIL too